# Sencha Architect (IDE) not showing build button why?

Tags: extjs, ide, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Sencha Architect not showing build button. Any reasons why? Here is a picture of what I'm seeing:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Install Ruby
2. Install Java Runtime Environment
3. Apache Ant

Check current status at Dependencies section (Menu > Edit > Preferences)

[More Info](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/getting_started/installation_setup.html)

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Also make sure Build Tools is Enabled from the Project Settings -> Framework tab